# Javascript date time format on my machine has changed and I can't change it back

Tags: javascript, windows

I am facing this weird problem were the default date time format for javascript object has changed from "dd/mm/yyyy" to "mm/dd/yyyy"....due to this I am getting many invalid dates,

This is only restricted to one machine,(which I surely doubt someone messed up the system date  or something as I am not the only one using the machine),

I know the problem is only confided to the machine ,but I want to find the reason why this happened and how I can solve this

Comment: Perhaps he changed his Regional Settings? Sounds like he switched from a UK layout to a US layout.

Comment: I changed the religional settings again to dd/mm/yyyy but still the problem persist,do I need to restart the machine?

Comment: @ericosg—there are many, many "regions" that use day/month/year order, though North America seems to be one of the few regions to use month/day/year.

Comment: @Snedden27—some browsers completely ignore system settings and use their own, implementation dependent, format.

Comment: I am using chrome ,I don't think its a browser problem ,as couple of days it was working perfectly on the same browser...also I change the regional setting but to no use

Comment: irrelevant of your PC settings, your software solutions should always work independent. Perhaps give us some of your code and we can show you how to make it work independent of culture settings.

Comment: this is become a little more strange as when I enter any date like 
var d=new Date(27/02/2001) and then when i alert the date i.e alert(d),it show the same date for any date I enter i.e 1 JAN 1970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some information missing here. The standard Date object does not understand DMY-formatted dates or MDY-formatted dates. Instead it uses the ISO 8601 format (or [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)) for dates. So, for example, if a particular browser understands

```
var d = new Date("5/6/2012");
```

as May 5, 2012 or as 5 June, 2012, or ignores it completely, it's entirely browser dependent. The standard expects a date formatted in the form "YYYY-MM-DD" and so on.

Also the parameter in

```
var d = new Date(5/6/2012);
```

is being interpreted as 5 divided by 6 divided by 2012, which is a small number just greater than zero. This is interpreted as a time on the base day, viz 1 January, 1970.

So, for the base system's regional settings to have an influence, there must be some other code somewhere that formats dates as DMY or MDY or something else.